# how to fix pagination problem on laravel-vue-pagination package?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

i am using laravel-vue-pagination package for pagination on my laravel vuejs project.but when i click the next page it's not rendering and going to the page no.first page is loading fine.how can i go to the page number 2? here is the code.  is another component.i did it accroding to the documentation.still it's not working.

```
<template>
<!-- Blog Comment threats -->
<div>

    <h3>Comments (4)</h3>

    <ul class="commentlist">
        <comment :comments="comments.data"></comment>

    </ul>


    <pagination :data="comments" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>


</div>

<div>

</div>

<!-- blog comments form -->
<new-comment></new-comment>
```

```
<script>
import newComment from "./newComment.vue";
import Comment from "./Comment.vue"

export default {
    components: {newComment, Comment},
    props: ['post'],
    data() {
        return {
            comments: {},
        }
    },


    mounted() {
        // Fetch initial results
        this.getResults();
    },
    methods: {
        getResults(page = 1) {
            axios.get(`/api/post/${this.post}/comment?page=' + page`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.comments = response.data;
                });
        },


    },


}
```

Comment: I'm running Laravel 7 , PHP7.4 on Ubuntu 18.0.4 and have spend a whole night yet I can't even get the thing to render. I did follow the original tutorial

Comment: I think it's support issue